# Seeking for help, polynomial, periodic sequence, gcd

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, polynomials, integers

I am seeking for help about the following exercice : Let $P, Q \in Z[X]$, with no common roots, show that the sequence defined by $u_{n}=gcd(P(n),Q(n))$ is periodic.

My Idea is that we can see that $P$ and $Q$ are co-prime since they have no common roots hence from Bezout formula, there $N \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n\in \mathbb{N} : u_{n} |N$  and so $(u_{n})$ is bounded.

I have the feeling that we could build an argument with adherence values, because typically if $(v_n)$ is $T$-periodic $Adh(v_{n})=\{v_{0},...v_{T-1}\}$ we find the period in the last index. Here, after $(u_{n})$ is bounded, we know it's a sequence of integers, so it admits at least one adherence value, and the sub-sequences that converges are stationary from a certain rank (because they're sequences of integers). We note $Adh(u_{n})=\{u_{i(o)},... u_{i(p)}\}$ in ascending order of index and value. This last set is included in the set of divisors of $N$. So if $l$ is a divisor of $N$ such that $l$ is not in $Adh(u_{n})$, $l$ is not an accumulation point of the sequence, so it is "hit" by a finite (or empty) number of times by $(u_n)$. Let $E=\{u_0,..., u_{N-1}\}$ and $a=max(E)$, assuming $a$ is not in $Adh(u_{n})$ so we have $r> 0$ such that the set $A(r)=\{n \in N | |u_{n}-a| < r\}$ is finite. Let $M=max A(r)$ so for any $n \geq M: |u_{n}- a| > r > 0$ . So we can construct divisors other than $a$, but this process is finite: the idea is to show after $N$ steps the sequence falls back on the same value, but we can imagine some very chaotic deliriums I got stuck here.

Any help is welcome.  I would like to know if we can conclude with this idea, looking at the adherence values.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what adherence values are, but it seems knowing $\forall n \in \mathbb N: u_n | N$ is enough. Since $P,Q \in \mathbb Z[X]$, we have $\forall n \in \mathbb N: P(n+N) \equiv P(n) \mod N$ and $Q(n+N) \equiv Q(n) \mod N$.

If $d | N$ and $a \equiv b \mod N$, then $d|a \Longleftrightarrow d|b$. That means the congruence class of $x \mod N$ determines completely which divisiors of $N$ divide $x$. Since the congruence classes of $P(n)$ and $Q(n)$ are periodic with period $N$ (see above), the same is true for the set of divisors of them that also divide $N$. But since $u_n$ is the greatest common among them for each $n$, it is also periodic with period $N$.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the Euclidean algorithm we have that $P(x)a(x)+Q(x)b(x)=1$ for some pair of polynomials $a,b$ with rational coefficients.

We can rewrite as $P(x)A(x)+Q(x)B(x)=K$ for some pair of polynomials $A,B$ with integer coefficients (by multiplying both sides of the equation in the above paragraph by a suitable $K$).

Therefore, replacing $x$ with an arbitrary integer, we have that the gcd of $P(n)$ and $Q(n)$ divides $K$ no matter which integer $n$ is.

From this it follows that $u_n$ has period $K$. All it takes is to show the following:

If for given $j$ you have that $d$ divides both $P(j)$ and $Q(j)$, then $d$ must divide $P(j+K)$ and $Q(j+K)$ and also $P(j-K)$ and $Q(j-K)$.

In case you wonder how to prove this, write out what $p(x)=a_r x^r+a_{r-1}x^{r-1}+\cdots$ then show that $p(x+K)$ is the sum of $p(x)$ and some multiple of $K$.